# Counting the number of names for elements of a certain name.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm self studying the proof of consistency of MA on Jech's *Set Theory* (Theorem 16.13, p. 272). There is a step which I can't understand. To simplify the notation, I will try to "extract" the relevant fact he uses:

> Let $P$ be a forcing poset such that $|P| < \omega_2$. Assume that P has the ccc. Suppose that $\tau \in V^P$ is such that $1_P \Vdash |\tau| \leq \check{\lambda}$ for some $\lambda < \omega_2$. Then every $\sigma \in V^P$ which is an element of $\tau$ can be represented by a function from an antichain in $P$ into $\lambda$ (and thus there are at most $\omega_2$-many).

I don't understand why this is true (but I do understand the "and thus..."). I know that there are nice names (from Kunen's book) and that it's possible to count the number of nice names for *subsets* of $\tau$ (once we know the size, in $V$, of $|\operatorname{dom}(\tau)|$). I'm also aware of the fact (and, most importantly, the proof) that, when using the boolean valued models approach, we have that $(2^\lambda)^{V[G]} \leq (|B|^\lambda)^V$ (this is Lemma 15.1 on Jech's book).

These results both look close to the topic of my question, but the setting is quite different, so I don't know how to use these facts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $1_P \Vdash |\tau| \leq \check{\lambda}$, there is some name $f$ such that $1_P \Vdash f:\tau \to \check{\lambda}\text{ is an injection}$.  In particular, if $p\Vdash\sigma\in\tau$, then we can pick a maximal antichain $A$ of elements of $P$ below $p$ which determine the value of $f(\sigma)$.  The function which takes $a\in A$ to the $\alpha<\lambda$ such that $a\Vdash f(\sigma)=\alpha$ then determines $\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't make it completely precise. If $p \Vdash \sigma \in \tau$, then the set $D := \{r : \text{ for some } \alpha_r < \lambda , r \Vdash f(\sigma) = \alpha_r\}$ is predense under $p$. Then we take a maximal antichain $A$ in $D$. We consider the function $\phi_\sigma : A \to \lambda$ given by $r \mapsto \alpha_r$. Any generic filter $G$ that contains $p$ contains some $r \in A$ too (since $A$ is a maximal antichain under $p$), and thus $V[G] \models f(\sigma_G)=\alpha_r$. [to be continued...]

Comment: Now, to conclude the argument, I must show that if $q \Vdash \sigma' \in \tau$ and $\sigma' \neq \sigma$, then $\phi_{\sigma'} \not\equiv \phi_\sigma$. How can I do this?

Comment: Well $f(\sigma_G)$ is always $\phi_\sigma(r)$ for the unique $r$ which is in $G$.  So if $\phi_{\sigma'}=\phi_\sigma$, this means that $f(\sigma_G)$ and $f(\sigma'_G)$ are equal in any generic extension (containing $q$).  Since $f$ is injective, this implies $\sigma_G=\sigma'_G$.  This means that $q\Vdash \sigma=\sigma'$.

Comment: Ok, I still have two questions: 1) It seems that you are using that $G$ contains both $p$ and $q$. I think this is because $p$ and $q$ are actually the same. I think this can be proved as follows: if $\phi_{\sigma'} = \phi_\sigma$, then $\operatorname{dom}(\phi_{\sigma'}) = \operatorname{dom}(\phi_\sigma)$. This implies that below $p$ and $q$ we have the same maximal antichain, which means that $p=q$. Is this correct? 2) Are we fine with $q \Vdash \sigma = \sigma'$? Shouldn't we prove that $\sigma = \sigma'$?

Comment: (1) Yes, that's correct (I see I was slightly misinterpreting what you wrote before, but it works out with what you just said).  (2) I would assume in this context that all we care about is that we have a representative of each _equivalence class_ of names.  If you want to literally count all the names, I don't see any obvious way to do so using antichains (since names might have random redundant information in them), and I don't think the fact you're asking for will be true in general.

Comment: To elaborate on how counting names is hopeless in general, assume $P$ has more than one element and let $S\in V$ be any set.  Then there are at least $2^{|S|}$ different names which always evaluate to $S$ in any generic extension.  Namely, given a function $f:S\to \{0,1\}$, take the name $\{(\check{s},1_P):f(s)=0\}\cup\{(\check{s},p):f(s)=1,p\in P\}$.  Now take $\tau=\{(\check{S},1_P)\}$.  In any generic extension $\tau$ is just $\{S\}$, and in particular has cardinality $1$.  But any name which evaluates to $S$ is a name for an element of $\tau$, and there are at least $2^{|S|}$ such names.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot.